# Training data for phishing or spam tweets

Tags: twitter, spam, phishing

I want to do phishing/spam detection on twitter. 
I’ve got about 500,000 tweets through Streaming API provided by twitter. Then I extract the url appeared in these tweets and submit them to two blacklists – Google safebrowsing and Phishtanks to receive a basic judge of whether it’s a phishing link or not. The problem here is that according to my experiment results, I can’t get enough samples of phishing tweet. 
Are there any exsisting tweet data that have already be marked as malicious/normal so that I can carry on with my work?

Answer (score 0):

the url blacklist did not work well, because there is latency. u can use suspended account as the label, but you should pay attention that not all the suspended account are phishing accounts.